# Does there exist a function $f$ such that...

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function $f:[0, 1]→[0,∞)$ satisfying: $\int^1_0f(x) \ dx=1$,$\int^1_0x f(x) \ dx=\frac{1}{π}$, and $\int^1_0x^2f(x) \ dx=\frac{1}{π^2}$ ?

Can I multiply $f$ by some function (maybe $x$ shifted) to show this is not true?

Comment: Why are you so sure this is not true?

Comment: Hint: note that these equations say quite a lot, for example, you can calculate $\int (x+1) f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. Now, look for a nice $p(x)$ such that you can something about $f$ by the value of $\int p(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 5):

$\frac 1 {\pi}= \int_0^{1} xf(x)\, dx= \int_0^{1} (x\sqrt {f(x)}) \sqrt {f(x)})\, dx \leq \sqrt {\int_0^{1}x^{2}f(x)\, dx} \sqrt {\int_0^{1}f(x)\, dx} =\frac 1 {\pi}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hence the equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Applying the condition for equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequlity we see that $x\sqrt {f(x)}=a\sqrt {f(x)}$ for some constant $a \geq 0$ which is a contradiction (because this gives $f=0$ except at one point and $\int_0^{1}f(x)\, dx=1$). Hence there is no such function.

Alternatively, you can verify directly from the given conditions that $\int_0^{1}[f(x)-\int_0^{1} xf(x)\, dx ]^{2}\, dx=0$ which implies that $f$ is a constant. The first condition implies that the constant is $1$ but then the other two conditions do not hold.

Comment: So if $f\ge 0$ then we cannot have $0\ne (\int_0^1x^2f(x)dx)(\int_0^1f(x)dx)=(\int_0^1xf(x)dx)^2$... Of course if we drop the condition $f\ge 0$ we can find a quadratic $f$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are right. Non-negativity is important.

Answer (score 2):

Your $f$ is the pdf of a zero-variance variable, so you need $f(x)=\delta(x-1/\pi)$, which technically isn't a function.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe the down-vote was because  they didn't understand it. I don't understand it either but I wouldn't down-vote an A for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Just to complement.** By Jensen's inequality: if $f$ is not a constant, then, 
$\frac{1}{\pi^2}=E(X^2)>(E(X))^2=\frac{1}{\pi^2}$, where strict inequality holds since $g\,:\,\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=x^2$ is strictly convex. This yields a contradiction.

Of course there is no constant $f$ fulfilling the conditions.